# How to move elements in HTML with Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, frontend

I have a simple page like below:
[image: Page]

As you can see, there are 3 `<button>` elements there, but I want to move Cancel button to the right of the page as shown by an arrow in the image.

```html
<mat-card-actions fxLayout="row wrap">
  <div>
    <button type="button" class="action-buttons1" [disabled]="!filterDataSelected" (click)="onClearButtonClicked()">Clear</button>
    <button type="button" class="action-buttons2" [disabled]="!filterDataSelected" (click)="fillOrRefreshTableData()">Search</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button type="button" class="action-buttons3" (click)="calcelProcess()">Cancel</button>
  </div>
</mat-card-actions>
```

How can I shift only Cancel button and not the others? I put it in another `<div>` block, but I am not sure it is correct or not. I have tried to play around `margin-padding-align` inside of `<div>` definition of cancel button but it is not moving.

Note: all this code is inside of an `<mat-card>` block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you already separate the buttons in 2 elements, you could add `fxLayoutAlign="space-between"` to the parent element.
Like this:

```
<mat-card-actions fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutAlign="space-between">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

### Html

```
<mat-card-actions fxLayout="row wrap">
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>
    button type="button" class="action-buttons1" [disabled]="!filterDataSelected"
            (click)="onClearButtonClicked()">
      Clear
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="action-buttons2" [disabled]="!filterDataSelected"
            (click)="fillOrRefreshTableData()"
    >Search
    </button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button type="button" class="action-buttons3" (click)="calcelProcess()">
      Cancel
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
</mat-card-actions>
```

### Css

```
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, in my case works!

```
<mat-card-actions fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutAlign="end center">
```